# Htaccess access specify file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^play/([^/\.]+) index.php?task=view&name=$1 [L]
```

Show page game.

My problem: When I need to load some file (or access by address bar) with path: `/play/Assest/file-name.swf`. This return 404 error.

How I can access file but don't change `RewriteRule` above?

I tried redirect code but it's not working:

```
RewriteRule ^/play/Assets/file-name.swf ^/games/Assets/file-name.swf [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "...but don't change RewriteRule above?" - why is that? Are you not able to change the code? Or you are worried it might change the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` is missing an anchor to the end of the URL, so partial matches still get rewritten. Add a `$`like this:

```
RewriteRule ^play/([^/.]+)$ index.php?task=view&name=$1 [L]
```

Shahaf's answer may also help you (although it means the file system gets polled twice for every request, which affects performance), but with this above you are saying "only match play/ with anything but dots or forward slashes following it" which seems to be what you mean. Without the dollar it can have anything after it and still match, as you have found.

I also removed the escaping of the dot which is not necessary in a character class.

Answer (score 1):

Before the rewrite rule you should add conditions if it's not a file or directory

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```